# Noun as modifier—singular or plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, modifiers

Which one is correct?

- statistical models for process monitoring
- Statistical models for processes monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I've seen this question before.

Anyway, the common usage is to put the noun in singular when used as modifier:

- Statistical models for process monitoring

(there's no *verb* here; "process" acts an adjective, modifying the *gerund*"modeling".)

The alternative would be

- Statistical models for monitoring processes

(Here, "processes" is the object of "modeling". One could argue that there's no *verb* here either; it still behaves like a *gerund*)